# mysql : update on recursive category table structure?

Tags: mysql

I have category tables:

```
category (id_category, parent_id, color)
```

This single table is used to store categories, under_categories, under_under_categories thanks to **parent_id** field.

My goal is to update ONLY under_under_categories' color, that means those whose grandparent is not 0

Any idea ?

Comment: You mean father's father is 0 right?  if you want to update only the grandsons it means that it must have a father and a grandfather only the grandfather must be 0, I'm mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a simple `UPDATE` with `JOIN` query:

```
UPDATE category AS c1
INNER JOIN category AS c2 ON c1.father_id = c2.id_category
SET c1.color = 'magenta'
WHERE c2.father_id <> 0;
```

`c2.father_id` is the father id of the father. If its not equal to `0` then a 'under_under_category' is detected and updated accordingly.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e847/1)

Comment: almost good ! One level is missing: you gave solution for sub category. I need to sub-sub-c atgeogory !

Comment: @yarek Did you have a look at the fiddle I set up? Only sub-sub-category records are updated there.

Comment: Looks ok. But what about sub/sub/sub category then ? I think I made a mistake in my question, sorry...

Comment: @yarek Simply add another `INNER JOIN category AS c3 ON c2.father_id = c3.id_category`, with `WHERE c3.father_id <> 0`.